# Mac equivalent for find -printf

Tags: linux, macos, shell

Is there a MacOS terminal equivalent to

```
find . -type f -printf %P\\\\n
```

Mainly, I want to replicate the -printf behaviour on a Mac.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unix command line tools Apple ships are terribly outdated; sometimes 12 or 15 years old.

You can install `find` from Macports:

```
sudo port install findutils
```

That version of `find` has the `-printf` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always going to start your search from `.`, you should be able to use this:

```
$  find . -type f | sed -e 's/\.\///'
```